# Div positioning on the screen

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have these two styles that position my div in the footer of my page. What happens is that when you generate the content of the page for php, these div can override the content.

```
div.panel-foot {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    color: white;
    background-color: #333333;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 5px 100px;
}

div.panel-foot-information {
    background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    max-width: none !important;
    z-index: 1;
    color: white;
    font-size: small;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

So what I do is when the content is small they stay on radapé ie with `position: absolute`, and when the content is longer they stay `position: relative`.

Anyone know a solution to resize content dynamically?

Comment: are you able store that contents within that div in a variable in your php code?

Comment: A solution to what? You told us what you'e doing with your website, you didn't say what your problem is...

Comment: @MarciusLeandro You have a bad habit of not selecting answers. We take the time to answer your questions the least you can do is choose an answer. You've got 13 unclosed questions.. that's 26 points you would get if you chose answers on all those questions.

Comment: Many of the questions had left open in order to have a better answer, after most of the questions the answer was mine, and hoped he had a better solution. But I'm sorry.

Comment: What I want is when the contents of the page was overlap the text it changes the style of the div.

Comment: @MarciusLeandro, if you still need help, if you can reproduce the issue on a jsfiddle, I will take another look for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the other answers so far, I'm going to assume you have images and other things that a *real* website has, besides text.

I suggest using Javascript (since you've got a jQuery tag). PHP ultimately has no idea how much space the content will take up in the browser, so JS is your best option.

Have a look at my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mnt5pxyn/). If you remove some of the div content, you will see the footer color changes (because it changes the classname). all you have to do is plug in your own selectors and classnames and you're good to go.

```
// check the size of your conent div
// assuming it's got an id of "content"
contentHeight = $("#content").height();

// set the threshold that will determine how big is too big
threshold = 300;

// or if you want to make the threshold as big as the window...
// threshold = $(window).height();

// if the content height is greater than the threshold..
if(contentHeight > threshold){
    // remove one class and add another
    $("#footer").removeClass('green');  
    $("#footer").addClass('red');  
}

// otherwise, do the opposite
else{
    $("#footer").removeClass('red');  
    $("#footer").addClass('green'); 
}
```

Comment: Very good solution, I think it has to do only with options in the CSS style, but I will do so.